# Call class and inherit from another class - python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I am in a trouble. I wrote two classes, the first is the main gui for the software and the second is the login. Now, in the login window I need to write a small validation function. I wrote it but I need after I validate this function calls the main gui class and inherits from `Tk`. I know my code is very poor but I need help please.

```
class main_gui(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master, self.username, self.password):
        self.path = os.getcwd()
        self.master = master
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()
        master.title("main menu")
        master.geometry("800x600")
        master.config(background="white")
        master.resizable(width="false", height="false")
        master.iconbitmap(self.path + r"/img/icon.ico")

        self.mmenu = Menu(master)
        self.menubar = Menu(self.mmenu, tearoff=0)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="about", command=aboutme)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Exit!", command=master.destroy)
        self.mmenu.add_cascade(label="menu", menu=self.menubar)
        master.config(menu=self.mmenu)

class login(main_gui):
    def __init__(self):
        self.master.title("login")
        self.master.geometry("350x250")
        self.master.config(background="white")
        self.master.resizable(width="false", height="false")
        self.master.iconbitmap(self.path + r"/img/icon.ico")

        self.user_label = Label(master, text="user name")
        self.user_label.pack()
        self.user_value = Entry(master, textvariable=self.username)
        self.user_value.pack()

        self.password_label = Label(master, text="password")
        self.password_label.pack()
        self.password_value = Entry(master, textvariable=self.password)
        self.password_value.pack()

        self.login = Button(master, text="login" )
        self.login.pack()

    def validation(self):
        if self.username.get() == "admin" :
           main_gui()           
           root = Tk()
           hm = main_gui(root)
           root.mainloop()
```

Comment: inside `validation` you execute `main_gui` - as for me class `login` shouldn't inheret from another classes. As form you should use class `login` inside class `main_gui` as any other widget.

Comment: If `login` has to inheret from `main_gui` then you have to use `super().__init__()` inside `login.__init__()`

Comment: BTW: if you have program in folder `A` and you run it in folder `B` then `os.getcwd()` gives you `B` but you probably will expect `A` to get image. Correnct path gives `os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])`

Answer (score 0):

The initialisation method of your main_gui class isn't quite right.  You need to change it to something like the following.

```
def __init__(self, master, username, password):
    self.path = os.getcwd()
    self.master = master
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    master.title("main menu")
    master.geometry("800x600")
    master.config(background="white")
    master.resizable(width="false", height="false")
    master.iconbitmap(self.path + r"/img/icon.ico")

    self.mmenu = Menu(master)
    self.menubar = Menu(self.mmenu ,tearoff=0)
    self.menubar.add_command(label="about",command=aboutme)
    self.menubar.add_command(label="Exit!", command=master.destroy)
    self.mmenu.add_cascade(label="menu", menu=self.menubar)
    master.config(menu=self.mmenu)
```

Do you see what changes I made?  `self` is passed in to the function as the first argument, and then `master` and `username` are passed in without the `self.`.  This allows you to assign their values to `self.master` and `self.username` in the body of the code.

Hopefully that does the trick for you.

Comment: thank you for your reply , yes , but my big problem to call the class from other class and make inhertance , look at the last part of the code please

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand.  Could you please edit your original question to include details of what you *want* to happen, and what *actually* happens with the code you have used.  Please include any error messages and unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is wrong. You don't need to inherit from `main_gui`. It make no sense for me.

It looks like you have two separated windows which you could use in two ways.

First:

- create Login as main window,
- get login/password,
- destroy Login (so yo will not have main window),
- create MainGUI as main window (using login/password as parameters)
- use MainGUI

Second:

- create MainGUI as main window (you can hide it or not),
- create Login as child/subwindow/dialog (not as main window) using `Toplevel`,
- get login/password (and put in MainGUI which is Login`s parent)
- destroy Login (so yo still have MainGUI as main window),
- use MainGUI (after you unhide it)

Both situation doesn't need to inherit

---

First version could look like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import os

class MainGui():

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.master = Tk()

        self.path = os.getcwd()
        self.path = os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])

        self.username = StringVar(value=username)
        self.password = StringVar(value=password)

        self.master.title("main menu")
        self.master.geometry("800x600")
        self.master.config(background="white")
        self.master.resizable(width="false", height="false")
        #master.iconbitmap(self.path + r"/img/icon.ico")

        self.mmenu = Menu(self.master)
        self.menubar = Menu(self.mmenu ,tearoff=0)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="about",command=self.aboutme)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Exit!", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.mmenu.add_cascade(label="menu", menu=self.menubar)

        self.master.config(menu=self.mmenu)

        self.master.mainloop()

    def aboutme(self):
        pass


class Login():

    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk()

        self.path = os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])

        self.master.title("login")
        self.master.geometry("350x250")
        self.master.config(background="white")
        self.master.resizable(width="false", height="false")
        #self.master.iconbitmap(self.path + r"/img/icon.ico")

        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()

        self.user_label = Label(self.master, text="user name")
        self.user_label.pack()
        self.user_value = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.username)
        self.user_value.pack()


        self.password_label = Label(self.master, text="password")
        self.password_label.pack()
        self.password_value = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.password)
        self.password_value.pack()

        self.login = Button(self.master, text="login", command=self.validation)
        self.login.pack()

        self.message = Label(self.master)
        self.message.pack()

        self.message.mainloop()

    def validation(self):
        if self.username.get() == "admin" :
            self.master.destroy()
            MainGui(self.username.get(), self.password)
        else:
            self.message['text'] = "Wrong !!!"

# --- start ---     

Login()
```